# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in React when rendering the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, reactjs

I get the following error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &
```

when rendering the client after having rendered correctly the server

This is my code

**app.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";

import Excel from "./components/Excel";

var initialState = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('initial-state').innerHTML);

React.render(
  <Excel header={initialState['header']} initialData={initialState['initialData']}/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

---

**Excel component**

```
import * as React from "react";

import { IExcelProps } from "../interfaces/ExcelProps";
import { IExcelState } from "../interfaces/ExcelState";

class Excel extends React.Component<IExcelProps, IExcelState> {

  name = "Excel";

  static propTypes: React.ValidationMap<any> = {
    header: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(
      React.PropTypes.string
    ).isRequired,
    initialData: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(
      React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.string)
    ).isRequired
  }

  // this correspond to getInitialState
  initialState : IExcelState = {
    data: this.props.initialData
  };

  constructor(excelProps: IExcelProps) {
    super(excelProps);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState(new ExcelState(this.initialState.data));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="panel panel-default">
        <div className="panel-heading">Airports Codes</div>
        <table className="table">
          <thead onClick={this._sort}>
            <tr>
              {this._renderHeader(this.props.header)}
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this._renderTableBody(this.state.data)}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }

  private _renderHeader(header: string[]) : React.ReactElement<any>[] {
    return header.map(function(value, idx) {
      return <th key={idx}>{value}</th>
    });
  }

  private _renderTableBody(body: string[][]) : React.ReactElement<any>[] {
    return (
      body.map((row, idx) => {
        return (
          <tr key={idx}>
          {
            row.map((value, idx) => {
              return <td key={idx}>{idx === 1 ? this._beautifyTypeColumn(value) : value}</td>
            })
          }
          </tr>
        );
      })
    );
  }

  private _sort(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // this get the cellIndex corresponding with the header column
    let column = e.target.cellIndex;
    // returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object.
    let dataTemp = this.state.data.slice();
    this.setState(new ExcelState(dataTemp.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      return b[column] - a[column];
    })));
  }

  private _beautifyTypeColumn(value: string) : string {
    return this._capitalizeEachWord(value.replace('_', ' '));
  }

  private _capitalizeEachWord(value: string) : string {
    return value.replace(/\w\S*/g, (txt) => {
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
  }
}

// XXX: move somewhere else
class ExcelState implements IExcelState {

  data : string[][];

  constructor(data: string[][]) {
    this.data = data;
  }
}

export default Excel;
```

---

**express route**

```
export function index(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: Function) {
    fs.readFileAsync(
        path.join(__dirname, '..', 'mockData/airport-codes.csv'),
        'utf-8'
    ).then((content) => {
        return csv.parseAsync(content);
    }).then((parsedContent: Array<string[]>[]) => {

        let element = {
            header: [
                "ID", "Type", "Name", "Latitude (deg)", "Longitude (deg)", "Elevation", "Continent", "Country ISO", "Region ISO", "Municipality", "GPS Code", "IATA Code", "Local Code"
            ],
            initialData: parsedContent
        };

        ResponseHelper.renderTemplate('index', res, {
            output: React.renderToString(React.createElement(Excel, element)),
            initialState: JSON.stringify(element)
        });
    }).catch(next);
}
```

I use browserify to place react code in the browser. Here is the complete example 
https://github.com/mazzy89/expressjs-typescript branch reactjs

Answer (score 0):

I would guess this has nothing to do with React and the error is here:

```
var initialState = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('initial-state').innerHTML);
```

If you're trying to parse the value of `innerHTML` as JSON, then it's probably failing because it has HTML entities, e.g. `&quot;`. Depending on the type of element, it may work to use `innerText` instead:

```
var initialState = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('initial-state').innerText);
```

Comment: Fixed. the problem is releated to jade template. the initialState has to be unescaped

Comment: Unfortunately I have another issue but this time is related to React. when I click to head it says that this.state.data is not defined in the _sort function

Comment: You should post that as another question.